# Difference betweenすればいい and すれば

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 私は何をすれば？

I thought that すれば only stood for the conditional form, how come does it bear the same meaning as すればいい ?

Comment: I think the title and the body question are somewhat different ... if you mean the body one, please edit the title.

Comment: It sounds like an informal, maybe not grammatically very correct? but still understandable, abbreviation.

Comment: To me, 何をすれば is incomplete and I'd either be waiting for the speaker to finish the question, or have to guess at the intended question from context.

Comment: @Philippe: I recommend you to fulfill your excellent comment a little more and post it as an answer.

Comment: Well, I'm not sure how I should interpret your answers. It really was the only question and it was translated in english as "What should I do ?" The character in question usually use keigo but the informal-thing can be explained with the fact that the character asked this question to someone they don't like very much.

Comment: `The character in question usually uses keigo` Then it could be short for 「私は何をすれば（いいですか・いいんですか・よろしいですか etc.）？」 cf:「ご覧になってみては？」=「ご覧になってみてはいかがでしょう？」

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 私は何をすれば？

In speech, this is a perfectly valid question, and semantically it means exactly the same thing as "私は何をすればいい((の)ですか)?" The last part is omitted because it's obvious.

To make the first sentence sound valid and natural, all you have to do is use the rising intonation at the end of the sentence to indicate it's a question. Maybe this could sound slightly blunt, cold or business-like if said in a non-urgent situation. But this would largely depend on how the character usually speaks.